# perform groupBy from underscore.js without applying sort order

Tags: underscore.js

I've applied groupBy to collection and it applies default sorting on column which is used for groupBy operation

```
_.groupBy(result, "ColumnName")
```

I don't want to apply sorting to my collection, want to preserve order of collection, but i dont see any proper documentation from underscore.js for groupBy method without sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `_.groupBy` from `Underscore.js` is when we perform on `numeric` property of collection it does apply `ascending` sorting automatically, and for `string` property it does preserves the sequence of collection.

So if someone is using `_.groupBy` on `numeric` property then need to apply sorting again on grouped collection if want to apply specific sort order on collection.

I believe there is not other way to avoid sorting while performing `groupBy` with `underscore.js` library on `numeric` property, It's a limitation.